# To count X of imgs, create n°X of divs and append imgs to divs created

Tags: html, image, each, counter

Morning guys,
i've a problem with divs and imgs..

so, i've, for example, a number X of imgs into a div (in this case, #content_project), now i want create number X (from number of imgs) of div (in this case, #content), append it one by one (each) of the previously called img, append all of this created (#content) into #contenitore_project and, the end, remove the old img from div #content_project.

so, this is the before code:

```
<div id="content_project">
    <a><img src="#" /></a>
    <a><img src="#" /></a>
    <a><img src="#" /></a>
</div>

<div id="contenitore_project">
</div>
```

and i want to happen this with jquery:

```
<div id="content_project">
</div>

<div id="contenitore_project">
    <div id="content"><img src="#" /></div>
    <div id="content"><img src="#" /></div>
    <div id="content"><img src="#" /></div>
</div>
```

i hope that you've understand.

Frank

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`.

Comment: Are you saying this is what is currently happening, or this is what you WANT to happen?

Comment: want to happen!!! for Blender: what do you mean?

Comment: @user12932: You have three elements with an `id` of `content`. You can't have more than one element with a particular `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
$('#content_project img').unwrap().wrap('<div class="content">').parent().appendTo('#contenitore_project');
```

- `$('#content_project img')` selects your image tags.
- `.unwrap()` gets rid of their parent `<a>` tags.
- `.wrap()` wraps each one with its own `<div class="content">` element.
- `.parent()` selects the `<div>`, not the `<img>` tag.
- `.appendTo('#contenitore_project')` moves them all to that other element.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QyYeX/**